# How can I create a table with blank cell and place the data to the right cell using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

**This is the xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="S2.xsl"?>
<forecast queryTime="30/12/2019 12:00:50" queryLocation="Singapore">
 <weather yyyymmdd="20190811">
  <year>2019</year>
  <month>8</month>
  <date>11</date>
  <dayOfWeek>Sun</dayOfWeek>
  <overall>Considerable clouds</overall>
  <overallCode>cloudy</overallCode>
  <highest>28</highest>
  <lowest>18</lowest>
</weather>
<weather yyyymmdd="20190812">
  <year>2019</year>
  <month>8</month>
  <date>12</date>
  <dayOfWeek>Mon</dayOfWeek>
  <overall>Cloudy with a thunderstorm</overall>
  <overallCode>thunderstorm</overallCode>
  <highest>25</highest>
  <lowest>14</lowest>
</weather>
<weather yyyymmdd="20190809">
  <year>2019</year>
  <month>8</month>
  <date>09</date>
  <dayOfWeek>Fri</dayOfWeek>
  <overall>A morning shower, then rain</overall>
  <overallCode>rain</overallCode>
  <highest>29</highest>
  <lowest>20</lowest>
</weather>
<weather yyyymmdd="20190810">
  <year>2019</year>
  <month>8</month>
  <date>10</date>
  <dayOfWeek>Sat</dayOfWeek>
  <overall>Partly sunny</overall>
  <overallCode>partlySunny</overallCode>
  <highest>31</highest>
  <lowest>22</lowest>
</weather>
<weather yyyymmdd="20190808">
  <year>2019</year>
  <month>8</month>
  <date>08</date>
  <dayOfWeek>Thu</dayOfWeek>
  <overall>Plenty of sunshine</overall>
  <overallCode>sunny</overallCode>
  <highest>35</highest>
  <lowest>21</lowest>
</weather>
```

**I need to create something like this**

[image]

**Here's the xsl i created**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
 <xsl:template match="/forecast">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Singapore forecast</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>Singapore<xsl:value-of select="@queryTime"/></h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#FFA500">
       <th style="text-align:central"><b>Date</b></th>
       <th style="text-align:central"><b>Mon</b></th>
       <th style="text-align:central"><b>Tue</b></th>
       <th style="text-align:central"><b>wed</b></th>
       <th style="text-align:central"><b>Thu</b></th>
       <th style="text-align:central"><b>Fri</b></th>
       <th style="text-align:central"><b>Sat</b></th>
       <th style="text-align:central"><b>Sun</b></th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="weather">
        <xsl:sort select="date"/>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#FFA500">
            <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="month"/>
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
          </td>

          <td align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="lowest"/>
            <xsl:text>° - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="highest"/>
            <xsl:text>°</xsl:text>
            <img>
              <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:text>image/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="overallCode"/>
                <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </img>
            <p>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="overall='Considerable clouds'">
                <span style="color:green">
                  <xsl:value-of select="overall"/>
                </span>
              </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="overall='Partly sunny'">
                  <span style="color:red">
                    <xsl:value-of select="overall"/>
                  </span>
                </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="overall='Plenty of sunshine'">
                    <span style="color:red">
                      <xsl:value-of select="overall"/>
                    </span>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <span style="color:blue">
                      <xsl:value-of select="overall"/>
                    </span>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This is what i get**
I can't place the data under the right date.
Also table is not formed correctly.
Do I start with  before the temperature,img and overallcode? because it seems like they have aligned on one column. How can I design to make these information appear on the right date?

[image: wrong forecast calendar]

Comment: Your XML file has weather  data for 5 consecutive days, starting from Thursday and ending on Monday. If you want to show a table representing a calendar where each row is a week and each cell is a date, you must first construct such table, then fill the cells that correspond to the dates for which you have weather data with the data from the XML. This is going to be quite a challenge if you're limited to XSLT 1.0, as it seems from your attempt - and not trivial in higher versions either. If this is homework, I would suggest you look for another teacher.

Comment: Hi, thank you Michael, so there is no way for me to edit this xsl to make it work?

Comment: Sure there is. But you must first (1) find the earliest date for which you have weather data; (2) calculate the date of the first Monday before or on that date; (3) create a row of 7 cells with the dates of the week of that Monday; (4) for each cell, calculate its date and if there is a matching entry in the source XML, get its data; (5) continue to create the next row until the date of Monday is greater than the  latest date for which you have weather data. Each one of these deserves a separate question. ...

Comment: ... This is assuming you want to have exactly the number of rows that are required to span the dates for which you have weather data. -- And BTW, there is no way that I know of to have a Date column like the one you show in your expected result, because a week can have - and in your example does have - more than one dates of forecast.

Answer (score -1):

There is a xsl that will give you the weeknumber of a date, see: http://exslt.org/date/functions/week-in-year/date.week-in-year.template.xsl

If thou would include that into your xslt and change your xslt into something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
  exclude-result-prefixes="date"
  >
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  
  <xsl:include href="week-from-date.xsl"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/forecast">
    <xsl:variable name="withWeekNumbers">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="addWeekNumber"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="sorted">
      <xsl:for-each select="$withWeekNumbers/weather">
        <xsl:sort select="@week"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@day"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currentWeek" select="@week"/>
        <xsl:if test="not( preceding-sibling::*[@week=$currentWeek])">
          <week week="{@week}">
            <xsl:copy-of select=".| following-sibling::*[@week=$currentWeek]"/>
          </week>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Singapore forecast</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Singapore<xsl:value-of select="@queryTime"/></h1>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#FFA500">
            <th style="text-align:central"><b>Date</b></th>
            <th style="text-align:central"><b>Mon</b></th>
            <th style="text-align:central"><b>Tue</b></th>
            <th style="text-align:central"><b>Wed</b></th>
            <th style="text-align:central"><b>Thu</b></th>
            <th style="text-align:central"><b>Fri</b></th>
            <th style="text-align:central"><b>Sat</b></th>
            <th style="text-align:central"><b>Sun</b></th>
          </tr>
          <!-- first loop thrue available weeks -->
          <xsl:for-each select="$sorted/week">
            <xsl:variable name="week" select="."/>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFA500">
                <xsl:value-of select="$week/@week"/>
              </td>
              <!-- Then loop thrue the days of the week -->
              <xsl:for-each select="$days/days/day">
                <xsl:variable name="day" select="."/>
                <!-- check if there is a weather element for this day. En if yes, use that. -->
                <xsl:variable name="dayWithForcast" select="$week/weather[@day=$day]"/>
                <td align="center">
                  <xsl:if test="$dayWithForcast">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dayWithForcast/lowest"/>
                    <xsl:text>° - </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$dayWithForcast/highest"/>
                    <xsl:text>°</xsl:text>
                    <img>
                      <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:text>image/</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$dayWithForcast/overallCode"/>
                        <xsl:text>.png</xsl:text>
                      </xsl:attribute>
                    </img>
                    <p>
                      <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$dayWithForcast/overall='Considerable clouds'">
                          <span style="color:green">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$dayWithForcast/overall"/>
                          </span>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$dayWithForcast/overall='Partly sunny'">
                          <span style="color:red">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$dayWithForcast/overall"/>
                          </span>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$dayWithForcast/overall='Plenty of sunshine'">
                          <span style="color:red">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$dayWithForcast/overall"/>
                          </span>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                          <span style="color:blue">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$dayWithForcast/overall"/>
                          </span>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                    </p>
                  </xsl:if>
                </td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:variable name="days">
    <days>
      <day name="Mon">1</day>
      <day name="Tue">2</day>
      <day name="Wed">3</day>
      <day name="Thu">4</day>
      <day name="Fri">5</day>
      <day name="Sat">6</day>
      <day name="Sun">7</day>
    </days>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template mode="addWeekNumber" match="weather">
    <!-- @day and @week attributes to be able to group them for your needs -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="dayNaam" select="dayOfWeek"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="day">
        <xsl:value-of select="$days/days/day[@name=$dayNaam]/text()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="week">
        <xsl:call-template name="date:week-in-year">
          <xsl:with-param name="date-time" select="concat(substring(@yyyymmdd,1,4),'-',substring(@yyyymmdd,5,2),'-',substring(@yyyymmdd,7,2),'T00:00:00Z')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*|*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You have a good start to show your calendar.

Comment: This has several issues, some of which can be fixed (such as producing data type errors when running on an XSLT 1.0 processor or failing at year boundaries) and one that cannot - because it is based on an assumption that the input XML has data for at least one day in each week within the required span.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: is meant as an idea on how to deal with this problem...not as a complete solution. There are still enough issues to be solved. But I would say, it's better than nothing;-)

Comment: I am afraid you are missing my point: the idea itself is flawed and will not lead to a solution of the problem - at least not the problem as you and I understand it (i.e. that the input has gaps between dates).

Comment: @michael.hor257k: correct, I did not understand the question.
I thought he needed for every week a row and for every day in the week. a cell. 